# Web API interacting with local application

Tags: web-applications, security, cross-platform, desktop-application

Situation

I have a Desktop Application and a Web Application.

I need the 2 to interact with each other. Such though that when a button is clicked on the Web App the Desktop App activates and replies with a form for the Web App to fill in and send back. My biggest concern is doing this as securely as possible with minimal manipulation from the Web App other than polling for the Desktop App, receiving the form, filling in the form and sending it back to the Desktop App.
When the Desktop App is 'activated' a password will be prompted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Whoa, full stop.  There is nothing wrong with a desktop application accessing a web application, but *not the other way around!*  This isn't to say you strictly can't, but you would have to install plugins to the browser and the plugins themselves would communicate to your application.

Give some serious thought towards reversing the roles.  Make the desktop application the controller and the web application as merely a means to gather information or make requests.  To put it in perspective, if you had a butler, the butler doesn't tell *you* what to do.  You tell the *butler* what to do, whether it be to perform some action or to give you information.  You need to think of the web application as the butler here.

That of course doesn't mean the web application can't have the type of functionality you'd also see in your desktop application, but your desktop application must *adapt* to the circumstances.  If you need your desktop application to react when something in the web application changes, your application can perform regular polling or perhaps keep an open connection to the server and the server can notify the desktop application.  But by no means should the server decide what the application should do when the event occurs.